# Building a simple Graal Native Sample with Maven

Tags: java, maven, graalvm-native-image

After a long, finally  I have been able to create a simple "HelloWorld" with Graal native , via command line using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 under this environment:

- Graal VM:   graalvm-ce-java11-19.3.2
- Windows SDK : Windows SDK 10.

I can't get it to work with other versions of graal ( *graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0-dev, graalvm-ce-java8-20.2.0-dev.*.), maybe for peculiarities of the local development environment ( impossibility to use Windows 7 SDK, eg. ..)

My next goals are to generate simple executables but with some more complex dependency, eg. the following vertx example

https://how-to.vertx.io/graal-native-image-howto/

Ideally my intention is to generate it using the maven plugin. 
If it is not possible, as an alternative creating a fat  jar and then converting it to native

**1. Using native-image-maven-plugin**

```
  <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
  <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.2</version>
```

**Error**:  Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.nativeimage:native-image-maven-plugin:19.3.2:native-image (default) on project demo01GraalTestClasses: Image building on Java 11+ without native-image requires MAVEN_OPTS='--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

**2. By command line after creating a fat jar**

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 19.3.2 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-19.3-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 19.3.2 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-19.3-b10, mixed mode, sharing)

[ **Important** ] call vcvars64.bat !

**native-image.cmd --verbose --static --no-fallback -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -jar demoGraalTestClasses.jar demo**



**Error**:

[demo:4920]    classlist:   3,964.94 ms
[demo:4920]        (cap):  38,810.44 ms
[demo:4920]        setup:  41,140.72 ms
[demo:4920]     analysis:  18,151.19 ms
Fatal error: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: class java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl not found
```

**Any idea ???** Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

I was running through the same error with no resolution. It seems that it is more plugin issue than the windows one.
I gave up and prepared ubuntu VM, run native image under exactly the same conditions like in windows(pom.xml, java11, graalvm 20.0.0) and it worked.

So I would either wait for next plugin release or tried to go linux way. Do not expect quick advice here.